# Typescript, is redundant var Okay in the generated js file?

Tags: module, typescript

I'm new in typescript. I'm playing with this code:

```
module app.controllers {
  export class BarController {

  }
}

module app.controllers {
  export class MehController {

  }
}
```

by using `tsc` with option `--module amd` and `outFile app.js` I got this result:

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    var controllers;
    (function (controllers) {
        var BarController = (function () {
            function BarController() {
            }
            return BarController;
        }());
        controllers.BarController = BarController;
    })(controllers = app.controllers || (app.controllers = {}));
})(app || (app = {}));
var app;
(function (app) {
    var controllers;
    (function (controllers) {
        var MehController = (function () {
            function MehController() {
            }
            return MehController;
        }());
        controllers.MehController = MehController;
    })(controllers = app.controllers || (app.controllers = {}));
})(app || (app = {}));
```

There are 2 `var app;` generated. I'm wondering that it should only generated once. Or even better something like this:

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    var controllers;
    (function (controllers) {
        var BarController = (function () {
            function BarController() {
            }
            return BarController;
        }());
        controllers.BarController = BarController;

        var MehController = (function () {
            function MehController() {
            }
            return MehController;
        }());
        controllers.MehController = MehController;
    })(controllers = app.controllers || (app.controllers = {}));
})(app || (app = {}));
```

Is that possible? and if it so, then how to achieve it? If it's not, then maybe is there any tool out there to simplify the generated javascript code like that to the result that I expected? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

No and it is not needed.

Because of variable hoisting there will be only 1 variable named app at runtime.1

You can find more about hoisting [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).

As for the modules being compiled separately you can't change that either.